# Python loan table trouble

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm currently trying to figure out how to iterate over over columns and rows at the same time [if possible]. Or wondering what the best way to approach this is. The biggest problem that I'm having is creating for loops with floats in simple ways. Our professor specifically asks for us to do that and then when we have to fill out the rest of the information basically accessing those loops. He doesn't want us to be importing different libraries and says there are simple ways for us to do this but doesn't really gives us guidance :/ Our table is supposed to be formatted to look like this: [image]

this is what i have in total already..

#### Supporting Code:

```
def main():
    print("This program is used to analyze commercial real estate loans.")

    #function variables
    purchase_price = input("Please input original purchase price: ")
    down_payment = input("Please input total down payment: ")
    APR = float(input("Please input APR: "))
    periods_year = input("Please input the number of payments per year: ")
    term = float(input("Please input loan length in years: "))
    first_payment = input("Please input date of first payment in form MM/DD/YYYY: ")

    #seperating str
    dates = first_payment.split('/')
    day = int(dates[0])
    month = int(dates[1])
    year = int(dates[2])

    #part 1 calculations with main variables
    total_payments = float(term) * float(down_payment)
    loan_amount = float(purchase_price) - float(down_payment)
    total_amount = loanCalc(APR, periods_year, loan_amount, total_payments)
    end_date = str(day) + "/" + str(month) + "/" + str(year + int(term))
    total_interest = r*total_payments
    #print("End day of loan : %s" %end_date) [do not need to print this right now]

#loancalc function
def loanCalc(APR, period_year, loan_amount, total_payments):
    #interest charged per period
    r = (APR)/(period_year)
    #amount paid in each period
    P = (r * loan_amount)/(1- (1+r) ** (-(total_payments)))
    #amount paid over life of loan
    final_value = (P * total_payments)
    #remember to return not print
    return final_value
```

#### Code that needs a loop

```
#loan payment table part 3/table will display
def pmtOptions(APR,period_year, term,loan_amount):
    #headers, each column will be 10
    print("{0:^80}".format("Alternative Loan Payment Table"))
    print("{0:^80}".format("=============================="))
    print("{0:^80}".format("Interest Rates"))

    #interest rate loop
    ##for APR in range(3,6):
    ##    if APR == 3:
    ##        print("3.25",)
    ##        APR = 3.25
    ##        while APR <= 5.75:
    ##            APR +=.5
    ##            print("{0:>3}".format(""),"{0:<3}".format(APR), end="")
    #printing interest rate loop

    print("{0:>10}".format(""),"{0:>10}".format("3.25%"),"{0:>10}".format("3.75%"),
          "{0:>10}".format("4.25%"),"{0:>10}".format("4.75%"),"{0:>10}".format("5.25%"),
          "{0:>10}".format("5.75%"),"{0:>10}".format("6.25%"))
    #never ending column headings
    print("{0:>10}".format("# Payments"),"{0:>10}".format("="*len("3.25%")),"{0:>10}".format("="*len("3.75%")),
          "{0:>10}".format("="*len("4.25%")),"{0:>10}".format("="*len("4.75%")),"{0:>10}".format("="*len("5.25%")),
          "{0:>10}".format("="*len("5.75%")),"{0:>10}".format("="*len("6.25%")))
    #attempting calculations
    #payments column
    for term in range(12,37,6):
        print("{0:^10}".format(term))

    #column 1
    for term in range(12,37,6):
```

Comment: Can you make that a minimal example?

Comment: First build a function that will print one line in a table, then build a function that will build one table, then build a function that will build multiple tables.  This will help organize your thinking.